# Approach to running Mongo Jest tests in Docker containers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, unit-testing, jestjs

I have simple API that I built with NodeJS.  It connects to a Mongo database.  I want to practicing writing unit tests so I installed Jest.

I want to write unit tests that will verify the correctness of my Mongo queries.  I found a package called `@shelf/jest-mongodb` as described by the jest documentation here: https://jestjs.io/docs/mongodb

I wrote a few simple tests and things seem to work on my local machine.  Now I want to run these tests in a docker container as part of my CI/CD pipeline.

I've tried various approaches and I'm running into one dead end after another getting `@shelf/jest-mongodb` to work inside a Docker container.   When trying to use a `mongodb-memory-server-core` feature, I get different errors depending on what I try. Sometimes the errors say there's problems starting an instance of `mongodb-memory-server`, other times an error says `mongodb-memory-server-core` isn't supported on `alpine`, other times it is something else.  I also tried to just volume mount my entire API folder, but then Docker give me an error like `Error: Jest: Got error running globalSetup - /api/node_modules/@shelf/jest-mongodb/setup.js, reason: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.cache/mongodb-binaries'`.

So I want to take a step back and understand how unit tests are generally set up when a database is involved?  For example, should I abandon the whole `@shelf/jest-mongodb` library all together?  Instead, I should just have Docker spin up a "test" Mongo database used just for testing?  Then somehow configure my `npm run jest` command to use the "test" database when testing, and `npm start` to use the "real" database when in dev/prod?

Comment: My personal recommendation would be to not run these tests in Docker at all; run unit-type tests (without external dependencies) in a non-Docker environment, and run integration-type tests by making calls from outside Docker into a fully configured Compose setup, but in both cases without including test code in the image or bind-mounting anything into the container.  But, if your CI system runs everything in a container (including the "not-in-Docker" tests), that doesn't resolve your issue, and there are other valid approaches as well.